# How to fill Flat List with nested JSON on React-Native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I'm new to React-Native, therefore, Javascript and I'm trying to understand how I can retrieve this data to be filled in my FlatList. The JSON format I receive looks like this

```
[
  {
    "18": {
      "sellingUnitName": "unité(s)",
      "qualifier": "GOOD",
      "sizeQualifierName": "gr.20"
    },
    "19": {
      "sellingUnitName": "unité(s)",
      "qualifier": "BAD",
      "sizeQualifierName": "gr.18-20"
    }
  }
]
```

Here's what my FlatList looks like

```
<FlatList
    data={ this.state.dataSource }
    ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
    renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.sellingUnitName}</Text>}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>
```

If the format is like this, my FlatList is working well

```
[
  {
    "sellingUnitName": "unité(s)",
    "qualifier": "GOOD",
    "sizeQualifierName": "gr.20"
  },
  {
    "sellingUnitName": "unité(s)",
    "qualifier": "BAD",
    "sizeQualifierName": "gr.18-20"
  }
]
```

My question is: how can I manage to use the first format by looping through each item and ignoring the first id (for example "18" in the first example) so that I can use item.keyName in my FlatList to display each values? It seems like I need to get the nested element but I can't figure out how to do this.

And if needed, this is how I fetch my data

```
fetch('https://www.mywebsite.com/test.php')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: responseJson
      };
     })
   .catch((error) => {
       console.error(error);
   });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `Object.keys` and `Array.map` we can get the data to look like you want.

```js
let data = [
  {
    "18": {
      "sellingUnitName": "unité(s)",
      "qualifier": "GOOD",
      "sizeQualifierName": "gr.20"
    },
    "19": {
      "sellingUnitName": "unité(s)",
      "qualifier": "BAD",
      "sizeQualifierName": "gr.18-20"
    }
  }
];

let dataObj = data[0];

let dataArray = Object.keys(dataObj).map(key => {
  let obj = dataObj[key];
  obj.keyName = key;
  return obj;
})

console.log(dataArray)
```

After this, dataArray will look like `[{keyName: 18, sizeQualifierName: "gr.20", ...}, {keyName: 19, sizeQualifierName:"gr.18-20", ...}]`